# Azure worker role automation

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-automation

I created my custom Azure Worker Role. This code is ready. What I'm trying to do is to create instances of this Azure-Worker-Role in specific Azure data-center, at the requested time. For example, I'm want to send command to Azure to create 10 instances of my Custom-Azure-Worker in West-Europe data-center - now.

It's important to pass this command also a parameter that will be the input problem to be solved by my workers.

I pretty sure that this automation task must be covered by Azure automation. Is that true? Looking for more information\directions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Management Libraries to create and deploy your cloud services from C# code. Just create application (eg ASP.NET MVC) to manage your cloud services by sending commands and deploy it also on Azure or even keep it locally.

See this article for more details http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to leverage the service management API to spin up and tear down roles. It can be accessed any number of way, including directly via REST.

RE: providing a parameter to the worker role, one option is leveraging the cloud service configuration file that you provide with the cspkg. Define specifics for the role there.

Depending on the complexity or simplicity of your scenario, you may also get away with simply having a table in storage that you personally poke with desired configuration values and that the worker can read to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Automation service should definitely be able to automate this task for you. Anything you can script via the [Azure PowerShell module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156055.aspx), can be imported as a runbook and called manually, via a third-party system, or on a schedule in Azure Automation.

Whether there is an existing runbook for the specific task you are looking to automate, I do not know. But Azure Automation has a [gallery](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/07/introducing-the-azure-automation-runbook-gallery/) of community-contributed content for many common processes, so this may be available there.